# Складывание отдельных элементов в списках Python

Tags: python, list

Хочу сложить все элементы из 2 ряда . Но выдает кашу из цифр . Подскажите как это решается.

```
universities = [
    ['California Institute of Technology', 2174, 37704],
    ['Harvard', 19627, 39849],
    ['Massachusetts Institute of Technology', 10566, 40732],
    ['Princeton', 7802, 37000],
    ['Rice', 5879, 35551],
    ['Stanford', 19535, 40569],
    ['Yale', 11701, 40500]
]

def enrollment_stats(universities):
    return (sum (universities[0][1],universities[1][1], universities[2][1],universities[3][1],universities[4][1],universities[5][1], universities[6][1]))
print(enrollment_stats)
```

upd.

```
def enrollment_stats():
    r = 0
    p = 0
    for u in universities:
        r += u[1]
        p += u[2]
    return r , p
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести результат чтобы получить вот такой вариант ?

```
Total students: 77,285
Total tuition: $ 271,905
```

Comment: Чтобы не возникало непониманий после исправления первой ошибки: ``def enrollment_stats(universities):`` - ``universities`` в этой строчке не имеет никакого отношения к списку ``universities``

Comment: Спасибо, а то я уже забыл это.

Comment: @andrew, ваш *udp* нужно оформлять отдельным вопросом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный код:

```py
def enrollment_stats(universities):
    r = 0
    for u in universities:
        r += u[1]
    return r
```

1. Не надо писать 0, 1, 2, ..., для этого есть циклы
2. Функция `sum` суммирует элементы переданного ей списка, а вы передаёте много чисел. Если уж хочется сделать через `sum`, то можно сделать так:

   ```py
   def enrollment_stats(universities):
       return sum([u[1] for u in universities])
   ```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы выводился вывод из цифр а не из каши например вот такой  <function enrollment_stats at 0x0000012E6231A840> ?

Comment: ``<function enrollment_stats at 0x0000012E6231A840>`` - это означает, что у функции не написаны скобки. Должно быть не ``print(enrollment_stats)``, а ``print(enrollment_stats(аргумент))``

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @andrew, если этот ответ помог вам, "примите" его (серая галка слева)