# Как посчитать элементы во вложенных списках?

Tags: python, list

Нужно посчитать количество элементов во втором столбце .  Я так понимаю  множественный список посчитать его с помощью len() не получится. Каким образом можно посчитать ?

```
 universities = [
        ['California Institute of Technology', 2174, 37704],
        ['Harvard', 19627, 39849],
        ['Massachusetts Institute of Technology', 10566, 40732],
        ['Princeton', 7802, 37000],
        ['Rice', 5879, 35551],
        ['Stanford', 19535, 40569],
        ['Yale', 11701, 40500]
    ]
```

Comment: len(universities[1]) ?

Comment: @splash58 Нет , то что вы написали считает количество элементов в конкретном кортеже , а не на весь ряд

Comment: Тогда покажите на примере, что же вам всё-таки нужно. Что это за "второй ряд"?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1572791/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-python

Comment: @MBo неправильно написал , получается столбец  начиная от 2174, заканчивая 11701. И нужно посчитать количество элементов , а не их сумму.

Comment: Если все подсписки содержан не менее двух элементов, то len(universities) даст то, что нужно, иначе нужно в цикле посчитать, сколько есть подсписков с длиной>=2

Comment: @MBo  Пробовал вашу часть кода. Результат 3 . А должен быть 7 .

Comment: Я код ведь не давал, и не знаю, что вы написали. В "иначе" я имел в виду то, что CraSmi в ответе написал. Однако, если формат подсписков гарантирован, то нечего мудрить, и len(universities) достаточно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Нужно посчитать количество элементов во втором столбце` как это понимать? если правильно понял то:

```
total = 0
for univer in universities:
    if len(univer) >= 2:
        total += 1

print(total)
```

Если вам надо посчитать СУММУ второго столбца:

```
total = 0
for univer in universities:
    total += univer[1]

print(total)
```

Comment: Если что то неправильно, просьба не минусовать репутацию, скажите в коментах и я удалю ответ. Просто я еше не могу писать в коменты под вопросом

Comment: Я сам новичок , поэтому постоянно спрашиваю что понять не могу и могу выразиться неправильно по незнанию . Но мне кажется в первой части кода , ты не ссылаешься на второй столбец , а  просто считаешь  количество списков . Вторая часть правильная ,но она мне не нужна

Comment: там проверяется наличие второго столбца, если есть, то тотал увеличивается на 1

Comment: Я просто смотрел на вторую часть кода там есть индексация на второй ряд .Вот и подумал что в первой части , ее нет значит что то не так .Но вроде ты прав .